# What is /snap/bin directory in $PATH? Can I remove it from $PATH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am working with environment value, $PATH. And I found that $PATH includes /snap/bin directory which does not exist. What does the path work? Can I remove it from $PATH or should I leave it?
 Please give me your suggestion. Thank you very much?

Comment: As a question more about operating system details rather than software development, this might be better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ (the Ubuntu-specific StackExchange site).

Comment: I don't know whether we should or not. But if you want to remove /snap/bin from your $PATH, just comment out all line in /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh

For more info, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: It's remnant of shovelware, of the Ca-NoNiCaL variety. To remove that last remnant, delete it from the /etc/environment entry

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a new-new Canonical thing to bundle and distribute applications.
See for example [this developer link by Canonical](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/).

Personally, I also find it somewhat odd that they went into the top-level via `/snap` but *Oh well*.

I may yet come to use it one.  So far plain `docker` serves me well, besides of course building `.deb` package the old-fashioned way.

As for removing the `PATH` entry: it only saves you a few bytes, plus nanoseconds in lookups and may break a future deployment involving snaps. Your box, your call.  I left mine.

Comment: There are a few weird edge cases. I came across this when I tried to dump the contents of my path and `ls` would fail, no such file/directory. It really means I didn't prepare for a bad path, but it's a bit of a pain screening for that. IMHO, changing the path is serious business and an oversight like that is a bit of an eye opener. In any case, for anyone looking to future-proof their installation... just make the directory!